# PYQT5 GIF freezes on GUI initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

Keep gif running while GUI starts. Is that possible? I have read many reporitys but none with the true and understandable answer.

I have prepared a code example that shows the problem.

[image: Own Gif]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QThread
class Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 500))
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        gif = QLabel(self)
        gif.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)
        self.movie = QMovie(r"C:\Users\...\Pictures\Icon_LOAD.gif")
        gif.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()


        #   #Call event handler to process the queue, but it is shocking, dirty and unsuitable
        #app.processEvents()
        self.show()

        for i in range(0,1000000):
            print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWin = Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The for loop is blocking, so it doesn't allow the event queue to properly process events (hence, the GIF is blocked along with anything else). What should actually happen instead of that for loop?

Comment: The GUI is initialized, i.e. it is described with values. Is there no way around the problem?

Comment: In addition, threads are started that include a camera, configuration files, etc

Comment: Anything related with the UI has to happen in the main thread, so there's little you can do: if the UI is *really* complex, the only thing that you can do is to "split" loading in smaller parts and call `processEvents()` between each pass; a similar concept can be done also when initializing other aspects, but consider that achieving a fluid animation while doing complex computations related with the main thread is really hard (and in some cases almost impossible), and almost always happens at the cost of performance (so, the whole startup process will actually be longer).

Comment: That's what I thought! Thank you for answering anyway

Answer (score 1):

#### Now it works smooth

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from threading import Thread

class Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 500))
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        gif = QLabel(self)
        gif.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)
        self.movie = QMovie(r"gif.gif")
        gif.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

        self.show()

        Thread(target=self.function_on_thread).start()

    def function_on_thread(self):
        for i in range(0,1000000):
            print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWin = Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```